# Add each element of vector to another vector

Tags: r, vector, addition

I have 2 vectors

```
x <- c(2,2,5)
y <- c(1,2)
```

I want to add each element of the vectors together to get

```
[1] 3 3 6 4 4 7
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `outer` with `FUN` as `+`

```
c(outer(x, y, `+`))
#[1] 3 3 6 4 4 7
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try creating each pair of x/y elements with `expand.grid` and then computing the row sums:

```
rowSums(expand.grid(x, y))
# [1] 3 3 6 4 4 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use variations of `rep` with `+`:

```
rep(x, length(y)) + rep(y, each=length(x))
[1] 3 3 6 4 4 7
```

The second argument to `+` uses the each argument to `rep` which repeats each element of y corresponding to the length of x.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
as.vector(sapply(y,function(i) (i+x)))
```